# saving MailItem in Exchange Agent to .eml file loses the email body

Tags: email, exchange-server

I've built an exchange agent to save certain emails to disk.

I can open the .eml files that are written to disk in outlook just fine, the only problem is that the body of the email is missing, also when I do "rightmousebutton - view source" in outlook on the email saved to disk I get an empty result (the subject and attachements are still present). The body is still present in outlook after I receive it (when sending the email to myself and opening the received message in outlook).

I've used the following code:

```
public void Write(Stream from, Stream to)
{
    for (int a = from.ReadByte(); a != -1; a = from.ReadByte())
            to.WriteByte((byte)a);
}

private void HandleMailItem(MailItem mailItem)
{
    try
    {
        using (var ms = mailItem.GetMimeReadStream())
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\email.eml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                Write(ms,fs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

besides mailtem.GetMimeReadStream() I also tried mailItem.Message.MimeDocument.Write but with the same result (missing email body)

```
private void WriteEmlFile(MailItem mailItem, string emailFilePath)
{
    _logger.Info("writing file {0}", emailFilePath);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        mailItem.Message.MimeDocument.WriteTo(ms);
        var byteArray = ms.ToArray();
        EncryptionHelper.Encrypt(byteArray, emailFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the difference between the good and bad (created by your code) EML files?

Comment: The eml files are fine in the sense that they open in outlook just fine without any errors showing the subject and attachments. The problem is that in both code samples the body of the email is missing.

Comment: So it is missing in the EML file if you open it in Notepad? Or only when displayed by Outlook?

Comment: hmm... when I open the email in notepad I can find the original body. So my question now shifts to why outlook does not show the body. When I compare the <html> ... </html> from the eml file (from within notepad++) with the result of right mouse button - "show source" from within outlook (with a diff tool) I find no differences. I'm using outlook 2010 version 14.0.7151.5001 (64 bit) and Exchange version 14.0 (Build 639.21).

Comment: It is really impossible to guess unless you post the full MIME message source.

Comment: Dmitry I really appreciate your help! The next 7 days an email with this problem (subject: "testsubject", body "testbody", no attachments) will be downloadable from the following link: http://we.tl/ermRTlnyn4

Comment: The message is in the TNEF format (winmail.dat), the HTML body you see inside is just the value of the PR_HTML property. Hard to say why Outlook cannot parse winmail.dat correctly.

Comment: so i guess this means your outlook also doesn't show the body?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a eml file, Check your eml header properties(contenr-type).
Ex)under the mime-version.
 content-type,encoding type..